# bind the selected item template to another control template

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I got a listbox with listing down item, each item is stackpanel with an icon and description text.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstSlectionTools"
         SelectedIndex="2"
         SelectionChanged="ListBox1_SelectionChanged">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Icon1}"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="Item1" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Icon2}"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="Item2" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Icon13}"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="Item3" />     
    </StackPanel>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Icon4}"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="Item4" />
    </StackPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I want to show the selected item icon something like:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="selectTool"
                Template="{Binding SelectedItem.Template, ElementName=lstSlectionTools}"" />
```

I am unable to figure out how to bind selected item (i.e. stackpanel first child's template to the selectTool's template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Binding.Path` in this case would be `SelectedItem.Children[0].Template`.